# Github Pages won't load video from Git LFS

Tags: html, git, github

I have an index.html file that has a `<video>` element (stored in Git LFS) set up as a background, however GitHub pages recently stopped loading it - it did work just a few weeks ago. There are also no issues in the console.

On the local server it works as expected in any browser, also all changes were pushed to git.

Has anyone run into a similar issue and would know how to fix it?

```
<!-- The video -->
    <video id="background-video" autoplay muted loop playsinline >
          <source src="assets/animation/star_burst.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          <source src="assets/animation/star_burst.mov" type="video/mov">
          <source src="assets/animation/star_burst.mp4" type="video/webm">
    </video>
```

[Link to the file](https://github.com/AnnaxT/AnnaxT.github.io/blob/main/index.html) in case that helps.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file was working a few weeks ago but is now moved to their [Git Large File Storage](https://git-lfs.github.com/) which means that `assets/animation/star_burst.mp4` is now a text file pointing to the storage location.

Try to specify direct access link. Something like https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/AnnaxT/AnnaxT.github.io/main/assets/animation/star_burst.mp4.

You can get it by clicking on "view raw" button on https://github.com/AnnaxT/AnnaxT.github.io/blob/main/assets/animation/star_burst.mp4

Or just upload less larger file.